# Зачем деревья экстентов в файловой системе ext4 имеют постоянную глубину?

Tags: linux, файловая-система, ext4

Деревья экстентов в файловой системе ext4 имеют постоянную глубину. Каким образом это достигается?

**Обновление**

Информация о постоянной глубине на этом сайте: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-anatomy-ext4/. Вот фрагмент

> Для больших (в том числе фрагментированных) файлов дескриптор может содержать ссылки на другие индексные дескрипторы, каждый из которых может указывать на концевой узел (указывающий на экстенты). Такое дерево экстентов постоянной глубины предоставляет мощный механизм представления больших, потенциально фрагментированных файлов.

Comment: https://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2011/03/28/digital-forensics-understanding-ext4-part-3-extent-trees

Comment: можете объяснить свой ответ, пожалуйста, я не очень хорошо знаю английский.

Comment: Только если вы перефразируете вопрос. "Почему" = каким образом это достигается? Или "почему" = зачем так сделано?

Comment: Вопрос изменен.

Answer (score 1):

Я не очень знаком с этой файловой системой, но не понимаю откуда вы взяли информацию о постоянной глубине. Можно почитать [этот](http://www.dfrws.org/2012/proceedings/DFRWS2012-13.pdf) анализ.

> The HTree implementation takes in a given filename and a seed, usually
>   from the file system superblock, and computes a 32 bit hash. As
>   discussed in Section 2.2.1, the hashes are then used to point either
>   directly to a block containing directory entries or to an index block.
>   Although the current limit to depth of the hash tree is two levels and
>   the number of directory entries that can be held in a leaf block vary
>   based on filename lengths, the root index can accommo-date 508
>   entries to directory indexes which each can hold up to 511 pointers to
>   leaf blocks. Estimates for the amount of directory entries that can be
>   stored in a single index vary, but all are in the tens of millions.
>   More details about this design choice can be found in Cao et al.
>   (2005), Mathuret al. (2007), and Phillips (2002).

Так что, если верить этой статье, то глубина дерева экстентов может быть **не более 2**.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.